# Is there any way to optimize query in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables as names `EPMDocumentMaster` & `EPMDocumentMasterTemp`
in same database where `EPMDocumentMaster` is having `ObjectID`, `ORGANIZATION_NAME`
and EPMDocumentMasterTemp is having `ObjectID` & `IdentificationVar` attribute

so what i did in update query is i matched the `ObjectID` of `EPMDocumentMasterTemp` to `EPMDocumentMaster` `ObjectID` and update `ORGANIZATION_NAME=IdentifireVar` in `EPMDocumentMaster` table

My query is below which will work on test database perfectly which is having not more than 200 rows,

```
UPDATE EPMDocumentMaster
SET ORGANIZATION_NAME = (SELECT IdentifireVar
                  FROM EPMDocumentMasterTemp
                  WHERE ObjectId = EPMDocumentMaster.ObjectId order by ObjectId) 
where EXISTS (SELECT IdentifireVar
                  FROM EPMDocumentMasterTemp
                  WHERE ObjectId = EPMDocumentMaster.ObjectId order by ObjectId);
```

but now the problem that i am facing is the tables are having 15 million rows and and the query is not working some how SQLiteDB browser get hang and stop working even my machine is having high configuration with 32GB ram & i7 CPU

So is there any way to optimize this query or any alternative suggestion

Comment: For starters, there's no point in using `ORDER BY` in an `EXISTS` subquery or any one that returns a single row.

Comment: Some useful reading: https://use-the-index-luke.com/ https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html